# How to configure an anonymously writable ftp server with vsftpd?

Tags: vsftpd

Sometimes we need to copy things between notebooks fast, and therefore it would be a great solution to have an anonymous ftp server running on notebook "A" that is writable by anonymous (of course chrooted, not allowing links), so that notebook "B" can copy/write there.. we need this with vsftpd.. I tried several configs, but it looks like SELinux is preventing this thing to work.. I googled for it (modifying SELinux booleans/SELinux permissions for the /var/ftp directory) but I'm still getting the same error message..

**Q: Can someone please copy/paste here a working short config for vsftpd.conf and the SELinux related settings to get this thing working?** OS is Scientific Linux 6.3 and vsftpd-2.2.2-11.el6.x86_64..

Answer (score 3):

As for the `vsftpd.conf` part, the following works for me (can't help with SELinux, sorry):

```
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_other_write_enable=YES
anon_root=/tmp/ftp
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_world_readable_only=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
listen=YES
local_enable=YES
nopriv_user=ftpsecure
ssl_enable=NO
syslog_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
```

Note that you can't write inn the `anon_root` directory - instead you have to create a writeable subdirectory and upload there.

Could possibly NFS be a better option? In version 4 it can even provide transparent encryption if desired.

Comment: selinux is the main problem, the vsftpd config works

Comment: don't need encryption, We just want to transfer files/dirs from notebook A to notebook B fast (with a direct eth. cable between them)

Comment: @gaskopeter even then NFS might be a viable option. Or SSH/SSHFS (the latter would enable native unix commands).

Comment: ssh uses encryption, so it's slower

Comment: @gaskopeter not necessarily - depends on where the bottleneck in the particular case is. There are also patches for kernel (and openssh as well, IIRC) which improve the performance a lot (which however is probably not what you want to look into).

Comment: The `anon_umask` option may be useful here too

Answer (score 2):

Use netcat (I'm using traditional netcat syntax - package netcat-traditional package from Ubuntu)

```
dest_machine$ nc -l -p 2222 > copied_dir_tree.tgz

src_machine$ tar czf - dir_tree_to_copy/ | nc dest_machine_ip 2222
```

Probably the fastest way (without encryption, with on-fly compression)